# Some operations on DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on praising a *.csv file. Therefore I try to create a class which helps me to simplify some operations on DataFrame.

I've created two methods in order to parse a column 'z' that contains values for the 'Price' column.

```
def subr(self):
    isone = self.df.z == 1.0
    if isone.any():
        atone = self.df.Price[isone].iloc[0]
        self.df.loc[self.df.z.between(0.8, 2.5), 'Benchmark'] = atone
        # df.loc[(df.r >= .8) & (df.r <= 1.4), 'value'] = atone
    return self.df

def obtain_z(self):
    "Return a column with z for E_ref"
    self.z_col = self.subr()
    self.dfnew = self.df.groupby((self.df.z < self.df.z.shift()).cumsum()).apply(self.z_col)
    return self.dfnew

def main():
    x = ParseDataBase('data.csv')
    file_content = x.read_file()
    new_df = x.obtain_z()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

'DataFrame' objects are mutable means that we can change elements of that Frame. I'm not sure when I'm hashing.

I noticed the use of `apply(self.z_col)` is going wrong.

I also have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Opinion, if your doing one-offs...look at functional coding style for this.  The reason you cant fix this is because the code was written for you...

Comment: That ”class” isn't one in the sense of object oriented programming. As Merlin said, write functions for this. When you get an exception please show all relevant code and the complete traceback so we don't have to guess where that happened and which code path led to the exception. Please show a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `DataFrame` `self.df` returned by `self.subr()` to `apply`, but actually `apply` only takes functions as parameters ([see examples here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)).